# How to connect to custom Provider using ethers?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, ethers.js

How do you create a new Provider using a custom node url using the [ethers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethers) package?

Looking to do something like this:

```
 const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider('http://my-node.com')
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the documentation [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v4/api-providers.html#connecting-to-ethereum) it says to use `JsonRpcProvider` instead of `Web3Provider`.

```
// When using the JSON-RPC API, the network will be automatically detected


// Default: http://localhost:8545
let httpProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider();


// To connect to a custom URL:
let url = "http://something-else.com:8546";
let customHttpProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url);


// Connect over named pipes using IPC:
let path = "/var/run/parity.ipc";
let ipcProvider = new ethers.providers.IpcProvider(path);
```

---

Update for **ethers v6**

`ethers.providers.*` updated to `ethers.*` for providers as indicated in the [docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/migrating/#migrate-providers).Additionally, to support [EIP-1193](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1193) the `Web3Provider` for `window.ethereum` has been changed to `BrowserProvider` as follows:

```
// v5
provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)

// v6:
provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum)
```

Comment: And this method also solves the problem of calling public view functions without signing requests. In other words, it doesn't require you to have a wallet connected or installed in your browser.